# Arranging elements with equal spacing in layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am currently getting the following result by using `LinearLayout` and `layout_weight`.

```
┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐ 
│        ┌───┐              ┌───┐              ┌───┐             ┌───┐        │ 
│        │   │              │   │              │   │             │   │        │ 
│        └───┘              └───┘              └───┘             └───┘        │ 
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘ 
                                                                  LinearLayout
```

Using this I'm getting elements which are equally spaced in the parent layout. The result I want is such that first and last element should be at end of each sides of layout and equally spaced from inner elements. What should be done in order to achieve this? The representation is given below.

```
┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐ 
├───┐                    ┌───┐                   ┌───┐                    ┌───┤ 
│   │                    │   │                   │   │                    │   │ 
├───┘                    └───┘                   └───┘                    └───┤ 
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘ 
                                                                     Layout
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Space view coupled with layout_weight in order to create equal spaced gaps between your elements.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<View
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="45dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<Space
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<View
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="45dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<Space
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<View
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="45dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I'm trying ur method but when I try to add imageview instead of view in above code the image stretches. Any idea how to overcome this issue?

Comment: How are you setting the image in the ImageView? You be should using `android:src="@drawable/your_image"` instead of `android:background="@drawable/your_image"`

Comment: It required some tweaking but working as expected. thanks.